# System generated integer entity ID's using DDD-style repositories with EF database first

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

We are implementing a DDD-based system in C#/.NET/EF database-first/SQL Server environment. Our domain entities are separate from EF-generated entities with repositories responsible for working with EF and its entities. I would like to have system-generated (vs. database-generated/auto-increment) ID's for newly created entities. The natural choice is to use GUID's but there's resistance to that due to the database size. The preference is to have `int` ID's.

NHibernate has a HiLo mechanism that I've used in the past but it looks like there's no analog (or at least production-ready analog) for this in EF.

What are the approaches that allow having a unique integer system-generated ID with EF database-first on SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

No, Entity Framework does not support system generated ID's. If you want to that you have to implement it yourself perhaps  overriding  `SaveChanges` in derived `DbContext` but I would not recommend you to go down this road

Comment: Not quite sure what you meant by your first sentence... It looks like you're proposing to use database-generated ID and this is exactly what I'm trying to avoid due to the issues in using this approach with Unit of Work pattern.

Comment: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/03/20/nhibernate-poid-generators-revealed.aspx

Comment: Talk about a 180 degree edit :) I don't think it's correct to state that EF doesn't support system-generated ID's - it obviously does and it works perfectly well with GUID's. It just doesn't seem to provide help with generating unique integer ID's.

Comment: I was not talking about GUID and I would recommend to use GIUD only when strictly necessary. You should have told us more about the issue you are having in your unit of work cos I don't see any issue using DB generated Id with Unit of work pattern

Comment: See the link I posted above.